# Pytest: using xfail together with raises, test keep xfailiing though unexpected exception

Tags: python, pytest

I'm about to mark tests as xfail with the decorator, and giving them a specific Exception that is expected to happen in the current development state of the application.

As I understand the documentation in http://pytest.org/latest/skipping.html the test should report a failure, and no expected failurel, if the test now fails or errors with a different exception.

Is the implementation different than I understand it?

Example:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.xfail(raises=AttributeError)
def test_xfailure():

    print "Hello"

    raise NotImplemented()
```

---

running it:

```
# py.test failtest.py 
============================================================================= test session starts ==============================================================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.6.6 -- py-1.4.26 -- pytest-2.6.0
plugins: cov, xdist, random
collected 1 items 

failtest.py x

========================================================================== 1 xfailed in 0.04 seconds ===========================================================================
```

Comment: Can you try with passing `run=True` to the decorator or the `--runxfail` command line argument? The linked docs are not entirely clear to me on this point but it looks like it might not run your test at all without one or the other of those.

Comment: --runxfail makes it really fail, as if the decorator does not exist at all,that's exactly as I understand it's description.



run=TRue should not be necessary with xfail, you see it is run in any case because when you remove the raise, it's reported as "xpassed" 

So the only thing that seems to be wrong is that the type of exception the test

Comment: Even if you combine `--runxfail` with it throwing the exception in the `raises` argument? (In your case, AttributeError)

Comment: ah, i didnt considered that option, but yes, it fails. so runxfail is really running as if the xfail completely is gone.

what bothers me is that the "raises" param to xfail  seems to be completely ignored, it simply doesn't matter how the test fails, it's accepted as an excpedted failure

Comment: stopping to further discuss it here as I'll handle it as a bug reported here: https://bitbucket.org/pytest-dev/pytest/issue/692/xfail-decorator-seems-not-to-honour-raises

Answer (score 2):

Solved with latest py.test version 2.6.4! Sorry...

The actual problem was, this seemed to be a bug in pytest 2.6.0
The development environment in the project were we're using it is a bit outdated, and I simply did not realize the minor version difference between 2.6.0 (also shown in the example output) and 2.6.4